# Layout in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, layout, smartgwt

How to place a control at the center of a canvas?

I have a main `VLayout` set to 100% width and 100% height. I want to place a grid at the center of this layout, meaning at the center of the browser's "viewport". How to do that with smartGWT layouts?

```
setLayoutAlign(Alignment.CENTER)
```

This places the controls center to the layout's breadth axis. But if I nest `HLayout` and `VLayout` it is not giving desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set the layoutAlign on all nested Layout panels.
the configuration is not inherited from parent panels and while HLayout defaults to TOP, VLayout defaults to LEFT.

Answer (score 1):

Also, make sure that you call:

`parentWidget.addMember(childWidget)`, instead of: `parentWidget.addChild(childWidget)`

The first one obeys `setLayoutAlign()`, but the last one doesn't.